# Mudar o ícone da linha da tabela quando clicar dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho uma estrutura de tabela da seguinte maneira:

```html
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Razão Social</th>
<th>CNPJ</th>
<th>CEP</th>
<th>Rua</th>
<th>Cidade</th>
<th>Bairro</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

E na última `<th>` existem botões de controle que servem para CRUD básico, visualizar, alterar, excluir, criar, em toda essa tabela.

Segue uma imagem de um pedaço da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho uma função que eu executo quando eu clico no terceiro ícone (*#disableCompany*), para fazer uma alteração no banco:

```
$(document).on('click', '#disableCompany', function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var uid = $(this).data('id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'disableCompany.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {id: uid},
                        dataType: 'html'
                    }).done(function() {
                        $.gritter.add({
                                        title: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Empresa desativada com sucesso!',
                                        text: 'A empresa selecionada foi desativada com sucesso! Ela não terá mais acesso ao sistema até que você reative-a novamente.',
                                        class_name: 'gritter-info'
                                    });
                        setTimeout(function(){
                           window.location.reload();
                        }, 5000);
                    });      
                });
```

Se o status (1 coluna) for vermelha (igual a 0, no atributo data-id), vou enviar para o script PHP e então irá ativar (colocar status 1) e **somente quando eu recarregar a página conseguirá ser vista a alteração**. Não tem como no lugar de reload() **atualizar dinamicamente**?

O código da última `<tr>`como foi pedido:

```
"columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": 7,
                    "data": "",
                    "render": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="getCompany" class="blue"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="red" href="deleteCompany.php?id_Company=' + full[7] + '"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="orange" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="disableCompany"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye-slash bigger-130"></i></a>';
                    }
                }]
```

Comment: Tem várias abordagens que podem variar conforme o seu html. Poste o html completo da tabela para que possamos analisar mais assertivamente.

Comment: É só isso de html, só o da tabela @DiegoMarques

Comment: Eu digo de umas tr do tboddy

Comment: @DiegoMarques, veja a edição se te ajuda

Comment: Alguma ajuda gente?

Comment: estas a retornar html em json ?

Comment: sim @13dev, aí é inserido na tabela. É o jquery datatables

Comment: isso é mau, deverias retonar só os dados necessários e ai sim juntavas os dados com o `html`

Comment: Tá mas e o de quando clicar alterar o botão? @13dev

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso, você precisará atribuir sua tabela datatables à uma variável:

`var datatable = $("#minhaTabela").DataTable({...});`

Quando você clicar no terceiro ícone:

```
datatable.on('click', '#disableCompany', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

// Aqui, estou atribuindo à variável row literalmente a linha inteira.
var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
    uid = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
    url: 'disableCompany.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {id: uid},
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function() {
    $.gritter.add({
        title: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Empresa desativada com sucesso!',
        text: 'A empresa selecionada foi desativada com sucesso! Ela não terá mais acesso ao sistema até que você reative-a novamente.',
        class_name: 'gritter-info'
    });

    // Neste ponto, estou dizendo que quero adicionar um pouco de HTML
    // na primeira td (coluna) na linha específicada (row).           
    $("td:eq(0)", row).html("O HTML que criará sua bolinha verde/vermelha");
    });      
});
```

**Observação**: Eu estou atribuindo sua tabela à variável `datatable`, porquê assim você terá acesso à inúmeros métodos que a API desse plugin oferece, por exemplo: `datatable.row("colocar a variável row").data();` recuperará os valores de todas as colunas da linha especificada.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, esse seu código irá modificar todos os atributos `data-id` da linha onde o botão foi clicado para 1 ou 0 de acordo com o valor atual.

No final, você pode alterar a `class` ou `html` do círculo.

```js
$("input").on("click", function(){
 valor = $(this).attr("data-id");
 valor == "1" ? (nvalor = "0", nClasse = "vermelho") : (nvalor = "1", nClasse = "verde");
 linha = $(this).closest('tr');
 linha
 .find($('[data-id="'+valor+'"]'))
 .attr("data-id",nvalor);
 linha
 .find("span") //Considerando que a bolinha é um SPAN
 .first()
 .html(nClasse);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" border="1">
 <tr>
     <td>
         <span>vermelho</span>
        </td>
     <td>
         <div data-id="0">bla bla</div>
        </td>
     <td>
         <input data-id="0" type="button" value="Clique" />
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
         <span>verde</span>
        </td>
     <td>
         <div data-id="1">bla bla</div>
        </td>
     <td>
         <input data-id="1" type="button" value="Clique" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```